# JMX - addConnectionNotificationListener not handling connection close

Tags: jmx

I am trying to detect shutdown of a remote server using a JMX connection.

The approach I am using is to

- create a JMX connection to Weblogic Server, and
- add a "addConnectionNotificationListener" to connector

Now If server goes down, I am expecting a notification of type "JMXConnectionNotification".

This does not happen. For figuring out that a connection is not valid anymore, I have to access it (By any small means) and when connection object is accessed then only my notification listener gets a notification. If done that way, it would not be real-time.

Can anyone point to me what can be done to solve the issue?

---

**My Code for reference** -

```
public class PrintServerState {

   private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
   private static JMXConnector connector;
   private static final ObjectName service;
   private JMXConnectorNotificationListener connectionListener = null;

   static {
      try {
        service = 
         new ObjectName(
            "com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
      } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
         throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public void initConnection
      (String hostname, String portString, 
          String username, String password) throws IOException,
      MalformedURLException
   { 
      String protocol = "t3";
      Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(portString);
      int port = portInteger.intValue();

      String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
      String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
      //String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime";
      JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname,
         port, jndiroot + mserver);
      Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
      h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,
         "weblogic.management.remote");
      System.out.println(serviceURL);
      connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL,h);
       if (connector != null)
       {
           connectionListener = new JMXConnectorNotificationListener();
           System.out.println("Created one listener for connector ");
       }
       /* try{
            connector.addConnectionNotificationListener(connectionListener,null,null);
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Connector does not support notfication Listener");
       } */
      connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String hostname = "example.domain.com";
      String portString = "7001";
      String username = "weblogic";
      String password = "password";

      PrintServerState s = new PrintServerState();

      s.initConnection(hostname, portString, username, password);
      String test = connection.getDefaultDomain();
        System.out.println(test); 

      for(int i =0 ; i<=20;i++){
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          System.out.println(i);
      }

      String test1 = connection.getDefaultDomain();
        System.out.println(test1); 
   }


   //INNER CLASS
   private class JMXConnectorNotificationListener implements NotificationListener{
        public JMXConnectorNotificationListener() {
            connector.addConnectionNotificationListener(this,null,null);

        }

        public void handleNotification(Notification notification,
                                       Object handback) {
            System.out.println("Notification");
            String type = notification.getType();
            if (JMXConnectionNotification.CLOSED.equals(type) ||
                JMXConnectionNotification.FAILED.equals(type))
            {
               System.out.println("JMX Connection failed!!!");
            } else if (JMXConnectionNotification.OPENED.equals(type)) {
                System.out.println("JMX Connection OPENED!!!");
            } else {
               System.out.println("Recvd JMXConnectionNotification status as " + type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the underlying implementation, you can't be notified as soon as the connection is severed.  Just think of a client socket - the only way to know when the server has shut its end is to try reading from the socket and seeing -1 or getting an IOException.

**You have two options:**

1. Leave it as is and get notified when you attempt to access the bean/connection and then do a reconnect on the spot.
2. Periodically attempt to access the connection (maybe just try to read the jvm runtime attribute or something not taxing) with a scheduled executor so you will be notified sooner.

**Which to use:**

If some scheduled service is polling data over JMX in the background, option 1 should suffice.

If operations are executed upon user request, option 2 is probably preferred so you can attempt to reconnect before the user ever notices.